# Magento : Disable Minicart Popup When User Click on Add to Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, mini-cart, popup

I need to hide minicart popup when user clicks on `Add to Cart` button but when user clicks on cart icon, minicart popup need to be displayed.

is there any way to do this in Magento 1.9.2.2???

Comment: Can someone help on this??

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Folders as this path: app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers
2. Copy file CartController.php from app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers to app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers
3. Go to line 198, function addAction() and comment this code:

> ```
> //$message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));      
> //$this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
> ```